# Can I 'invert' a bool?

Tags: c#, boolean

I have some checks to see if a screen is active. The code looks like this:

```
if (GUI.Button(new Rect(Screen.width / 2 - 10, 50, 50, 30), "Rules")) //Creates a button
    {
        if (ruleScreenActive == true) //check if the screen is already active
            ruleScreenActive = false; //handle according to that
        else 
            ruleScreenActive = true;
    }
```

Is there any way to - whenever I click the button - invert the value of `ruleScreenActive`?

(This is C# in Unity3D)

Comment: Even without a better optimization, you can remove all `== true` from your code.

Comment: It would be cool if there was an operator to do this like the `++` or `--` operator.

Answer (score 179, accepted):

You can get rid of your if/else statements by negating the bool's value:

```
ruleScreenActive = !ruleScreenActive;
```

Comment: I always use the exclusive or assignment operator: `x ^= true;`. Is prettier (in my opinion) and shorter in most cases, but does the same.

Comment: @Tobias interesting approach. Shorter yes, but readability is debatable. If I saw that in code it would make me think a split-second longer than the typical negation.

Comment: I think that repeating yourself in this instance leads to better legibility and is worth the trade-off.

Comment: Just an FYI to VB newbies: This works in VB.Net as well by doing the exact same thing: rulesScreenActive = Not (ruleScreenActive)

Comment: @jack DRY is not something that you can apply everywhere. For instance, you can't DRY it out when I put semicolons at the end of expressions every expression.

Answer (score 77):

I think it is better to write:

```
ruleScreenActive ^= true;
```

that way you avoid writing the variable name twice ... which can lead to errors

Comment: the syntax csharp should have: ruleScreenActive!!;

Comment: +1! This is exactly what I was looking for. This makes it a lot easier to flip a bool based on another bool ("abcd".Contains("s") ^= someNegateBool)

Comment: Good answer since you can use a variable to alter the boolean value!

Comment: A bit of explanation regarding the operators would've been better.

Comment: Explanation: ^ is the XOR cond operator, it is like a normal OR except if both are true it returns false instead of true, which means that you only get these two cases: 0^1=1 and 1^1=0 which indeed inverts the bool (the first bit). I like this method because if you do a Find All References on the bool variable this line will show only once (just like a bool++) whereas with the other method it will show 2 times back to back which is annoying. It is not harder to read at all once you actually understand what it means.

Comment: This is also a great solution if u want to avoid making garbage by storing an object in an extra variable to just flip a bool variable in it. Like `parent.GetChild(0).GetRenderOptions().flipX ^= true;`

Answer (score 12):

```
ruleScreenActive = !ruleScreenActive;
```

Comment: This is just a duplicate of the accepted answer.

Answer (score 12):

This would be inlined, so readability increases, runtime costs stays the same:

```
public static bool Invert(this bool val) { return !val; }
```

To give:

```
ruleScreenActive.Invert();
```

Comment: It's possible, but I wouldn't recommend it as it introduces two problems: 1. not every coder on your team will know (or remember) about this method, so you'll end up with inconsistent code where it's used in some places and in some others not, 2. at some point it will lead to confusion as one could expect it to mutate the value rather than return an altered copy (one of common silly mistakes in C# is forgetting that `String.Replace` returns a value rather than modifies it, even though people know strings in .NET are immutable). Naming it `Invert` instead of `Inverted`makes it even more likely.

Comment: And yes I know it's been a while : )

Comment: @Jack the name `Toggle` sounds better IMHO

Comment: Haha, @karlingen look at Konrad, maybe you mean `Toggled`

Comment: This also adds an absolutely unnecessary function call.

Comment: I guess that one could add the `[MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]` attribute to such a method to avoid the unnecessary method call. That said, I'm not a .NET specialist, but I think the .NET compiler may already detect that inlining is possible with this simple, pure and safe function. Better check with an IL decompiler to check that.

Comment: This actually should be `ruleScreenActive = ruleScreenActive.Invert();`  Just `ruleScreenActive.Invert();` will through the result away.

Answer (score 1):

This can be useful for long variable names. You don't have to write the variable name twice.

```cs
public static void Invert(this ref bool b) => b = !b;
```

Example:

```cs
bool superLongBoolVariableName = true;
superLongBoolVariableName.Invert()
```

Comment: This is just a repeat of Jack's answer and offers no additional value whatsoever.

Comment: @BillTarbell Actually, it's not. I use ``this ref`` to invert the bool without having to reassing to the return value.