# Nicer code for toggling a bool member

Tags: c#

Please note that the question isn't about negating a boolean value but rather about the most elegant, efficient and nicest way of doing so.

Upon a click on a toggle button, I execute the following code to store the new state in a private `bool`.

```
_isIt = !_isIt;
```

It works, sure. It's readable, sure. But so is `i = i + 1`, still, we always write `i++`. Is there a neater way to toggle a `bool`?

Comment: Is there a problem with what you have now? If not, then you don't have a problem...

Comment: @carlosfigueira It's not a problem of the kind "it's not working". It's rather an issue of type "can it be done better".

Comment: I suppose you could make a Toggle() extension method if you think that would be more identifiable in your code. It's completely superfluous though.

Comment: If you're asking about whether there's something like `_isIt !=`, then no, it can't be done better.

Comment: @carlosfigueira Exactly. Something like `_isIt!!;` would be great. This **exact** syntax doesn't work, of course, but I was hoping for something else, like that. If there's not such a thing (which seems to be the general concesus) I guess, I'm satisfied and happy. Thanks!

Comment: @AndreasJohansson, I don't think there is the need for any other syntax. When I read that line, in my head it is: "assign _itIs variable to **not _itIs**". IMO, it is very readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I 'invert' a bool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912353/can-i-invert-a-bool)

Comment: @ShooShoSha My question is about optimality not the actual operation. Those are a bit related but far from duplicates.

Comment: @carlosfigueira @driis "I don't think you need `i++;` because `i = i + 1;` works just as well.  There is no need for any other syntax." (this is the case in say... Lua for instance)  What about when you have to work with `thisVeryLongVariableName = !thisVeryLongVariableName;`?  Yes there are use cases.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

No. That's the optimal way. Congratulations!

**Even IF** there would be an other way (as you commented - `_isIt!!`), I believe that it would be better not to use it because you'd be raising a lot of eyebrows anyway.

Answer (score 27):

In fact there is another option to toggle a boolean value, this will work:

```
_isIt ^= true;
```

However this is not better than the way you did...

Comment: Haha, +1 for creativity. And you're perfectly right - it's not better. :)

Comment: I disagree - it's much more readable than:
`this.VerbosePropertyName.VerboseMemberClass.SomeSetting = !this.VerbosePropertyName.VerboseMemberClass.SomeSetting;`

Comment: @decPL, but maybe `this.ToggleVerbosePropertyName()` is better ;)

Comment: I agree - **maybe** - we can't really say without some more context. As a rule of thumb in all the places I've worked, we'd prefer `someProp ^= true` as much cleaner than having a separate descriptive method for such a trivial operation (in the same way `i++` is much better than say `MathematicalUtils.IncreaseNumeric(ref i)`), but obviously YMMV.

Comment: I like this solution because I was able to simplify toggling a checkbox like this: ((CheckBox)((DockPanel)sender).Children[0]).IsChecked ^= true;

Answer (score 4):

### A Quick Note

Though an answer has been accepted, I believe a more in-depth answer would be nice for future readers to have. As this post has pointed out, the `!` or `NOT` operator is the most widely accepted, and the optimal solution. In fact, when compared to `^` or `XOR` over 10,000 iterations it is roughly 100ms faster. The usage all depends on the circumstance to be honest. Either way, below you will find the three most common methods of toggling a `bool` value, and you should choose what you are most comfortable with using, within the standards you're allowed to use.

---

### The `if-else` Method

The easiest way to toggle a `bool` value is to write out an `if-else` that assigns the new value; this way even a complete beginner to development can understand what is going on. This is actually how toggling is taught in most conceptual classes.

```
bool b = true;
if (b == true)
    b = false;
else
    b = true;
```

Of course the `if` can be simplified to `if (b)`, but traditionally, you'll write it all the way out for clarity and learning purposes.

---

### The NOT Operator

As you learn more about development and logical operations, you'll learn about the `NOT` operator or `!` in `C#`. The usage of this operator is the most widely accepted in the industry for multiple reasons. It's simple, it's easy to read, it's easy to understand, and it's fast:

```
x = !x;
```

This breaks down to `!true = false` and `!false = true`.

---

### The XOR Operator

The `XOR` or `^` in `C#` is the less-chosen operator for this task, but it is an acceptable operator depending on the situation. As some have pointed out in comments, this operator is especially useful when dealing with longer names or deep-access members. If performance matters, and the operation will be executed multiple times, it's best to go with the `NOT` operator, as it is faster. If performance isn't really a concern, then using the `XOR` operator is acceptable; though in a professional environment you'll likely need to justify the usage.

```
b ^= true;
b = b ^ true;
```

The biggest thing to understand about `XOR` prior to using it for a toggle, is understanding how it works logically:

```
true ^ false = true;
true ^ true = false;
false ^ true = true;
false ^ false = false;
```

That logic table explains why `b ^= false` won't toggle. A `XOR` requires one side of the operator to be `true` and the other to be `false`. Which side it is doesn't matter, but neither side can be the same value or it will evaluate to `false`. Hence:

```
bool b = true;
b ^= false; // true.
b ^= false; // true. So on, and so forth.

bool b = false;
b ^= false; // false.
b ^= false; // false. So on, and so forth.
```

---

### Final Thoughts

The answer to the OP's question is simply:

- The `NOT` operator is the cleanest and most efficient solution for toggling.

I wish you all the best of luck in your future endeavors, and hopefully this answer helped to shed further light on the topic!

Comment: What do you mean by `x != x` in your explanation? You're not implying that is equivalent to `x = !x`, are you?

Comment: No, that was a copypasta from my code that I forgot to remove. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 3):

No, I believe that is the idiomatic C# way of toggling a `bool` (i.e. assigning it the opposite value).

My opinion: Keep your code as it is. It clearly conveys the intent of the code, which is the most important thing for future readers.

If you are interested in *alternative* ways of doing it, you could use XOR, but I will argue it is less readable.

```
_isIt ^= true;
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't. I don't know what else to add to this answer :)