# Changing bool values to opposite of the initial value

Tags: c#, c++, c, boolean

This maybe sound strange to you but I'm too lazy to write everytime like

```
if (threadAlive)
{
            threadAlive = false;
}
        else
{
            threadAlive = true;
}
```

isn't there is something like int++ or int-- to change bool value to opposite of its value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I 'invert' a bool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912353/can-i-invert-a-bool)

Answer (score 83):

Just do this:

```
threadAlive = !threadAlive;
```

Comment: @user1046403 in C / C++ you could possibly write a custom operator that makes it simpler, in C# this is as good as it gets.

Comment: Even if you can write a custom operator, do everyone a favor and don't do that. `b = !b` is idiomatic to anyone who understands the language.

Comment: maybe if there would be something like threadAlive!! that would be awesome. How could I write a custom operator? any help?

Comment: Your problem has been solved. Don't try to make it into a worse one. (Also, please pick up some learning material for one of C or C++ or C# or whichever you are learning)

Comment: @p.s.w.g In C, there are no custom operators.  In C++, at least one parameter of a custom operator must be a user defined type, or a reference to a user defined type, which `bool` is not.  (In either language, of course, you could write a macro which does it.  A technique which commonly goes under the name of obfuscation.)

Comment: @user1046403 Writing a custom operator is a different question entirely. 1) pick a language, 2) do some research, 3) try something out 4) if you have trouble, ask that as a new question on SO.

Comment: @JamesKanze I haven't used C++ since college, so I wasn't sure. I didn't want to say it was flatly impossible.

Answer (score 23):

Yes, there is!

```
threadAlive ^= true;
```

(this is a C# joke, in the most general case it won't work in C/C++/Javascript (it *could* work in C/C++/Javascript depending on some conditions), but it's true! `^` is the xor operator)

Comment: I didn't expect that to work in C#, but it does. +1 for ingenuity.

Comment: It's a bad joke, because the type of `threadAlive` wasn't specified. This would lead `"not true"` to be "true" for the _majority_ of values for `int`, e.g.

Comment: @sehe There is a `C#` tag. But added a note about languages.

Comment: It should work in C++ as well, provided `threadAlive` has type `bool` (and since he uses it as a condition in an `if`, that should be a safe assumption---although the language does allow other types, with implicit conversion, and I've even seen some programmers use them).

Comment: @xanatos Ah, I see, C# makes it illegal to use `^= true` unless `threadAlive` is of type `System.Boolean`. That means you redefined the question (assuming `threadAlive` is bool) as well as reduced the scope to 1/3 (only answering for C#)

Comment: @sehe The original question is marked with a boolean tag so I think it's a fair assumption. Don't think he redefined the question at all, also this is the most elegant solution.

Comment: Why should this be a joke? Isn't this exactly what xor was made for?

Answer (score 17):

This would do it:

```
threadAlive = !threadAlive;
```

The correct term is [Toggle](http://blog.andreloker.de/post/2008/08/05/The-almighty-boolean-toggle.aspx)

Answer (score 11):

The logical negation operator `!` is a unary operator that negates its operand. It is defined for `bool` and returns `true` if and only if its operand is `false` and `false` if and only if its operand is `true`:

```
threadAlive = !threadAlive;
```

Answer (score 7):

Use the `!` operator:

```
bool b = true;

b = !b;   // b is now false
```

Answer (score 7):

You can't [overload operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288467%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) for basic types if that's what you're looking for.

As everyone else mentioned already, this is by far your best option:

```
threadAlive = !threadAlive;
```

You can however, although is something I would never recommend, create your own `bool` type and overload the `++` or whatever operator you wish to invert your value.

The following code is something that should **never** be used anyway:

```
public class MyBool
{
    bool Value;

    public MyBool(bool value)
    {
        this.Value = value;
    }

    public static MyBool operator ++(MyBool myBoolean)
    {
        myBoolean.Value = !myBoolean.Value;
        return myBoolean;
    }
}
```

You can also create your own extension method but that won't be be a better way either.

Answer (score 5):

Very simple:

```
threadAlive = ! threadAlive;
```