# Changing a boolean every time I click a button

Tags: c#, forms

I have a boolean that is set to false at the start of the application. However when someone clicks the button the boolean is set to true and starts doing the code I've written. Is it possible if the user re-clicks the button, the boolean to become false again so the code stops running? Right now if I re-click the button it just does the code I've written which seems logical, but I'd like it to turn it to false if I re-click it, and then again to true if I re-click it, etc,etc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can I 'invert' a bool?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912353/can-i-invert-a-bool)

Comment: Are you suggesting you'd like the code to stop executing once you click the button?

Comment: Consider to use Checkbox for turning something on and off

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `!` unary operator for toggling the boolean:

```
_someBoolean = !_someBoolean;
```

Answer (score 5):

in c# there is a negation operator. (!)

so you could do something like:

```
private bool myBool;

public void OnButtonClick()
{
    myBool = !myBool;
}
```

this would cause it to changed every time the button is pressed

Answer (score 0):

Though other answers correctly explain how to toggle boolean field of your form, you can use something which:

1. Don't require additional field.
2. Gives nice hint to user whether some functionality is enabled or not.

You can use `CheckBox` control with `Appearance` property set to `Button`. That will make checkbox look exactly like ordinal button, which can stay in pressed state after user clicks it. You can subscribe to `CheckedChanged` event of this checkbox same way as you were subscribing to `Click` event of button:

```
 private void FooCheckBox_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    if (fooCheckBox.Checked)
      // ...
 }
```